# How do I modify number of words displayed for blog posts in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

When I go to the blog, only ~50 words per post are displayed. How can I edit this so more words get displayed? On the same note, how do I get images to be displayed as well?

Answer (score 1):

The default template for the summary of the body part (the main content for a blog post) strips html formatting and take the first 200 characters. You can override this by creating an 'alternate' view in your theme. The easiest way is to use the designer tools shape tracing feature to override the template:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools

The result will be to create a copy of the Core/Common/Views/Parts.Common.Body.Summary.cshtml in your theme's views folder and then you can adjust the `Html.Excerpt(bodyHtml, 200)` to the length you require.

As the summary excerpt strips out html, your images will be removed. You might be better to include a separate thumbnail image to using in your blog post summary. You can then adjust where this is displayed using the placement file. See this post:

[How to add Image Field to Blog Post Summary in Orchard CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131041/how-to-add-image-field-to-blog-post-summary-in-orchard-cms)

Comment: Find the template that I use for this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2012/07/01/my-body-summary-template-for-orchard.aspx