# Add Thumbnail / picture on the blog list summary orchard

Tags: orchardcms

How do I add image / thumbnail before the blog summary using orchard cms?
Please give step by step instruction because I'm still new using this cms
i already tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131041/how-to-add-image-field-to-blog-post-summary-in-orchard-cms) but still not working
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you enable the shape tracer module in Orchard, this will assist you in understanding exactly what is being pulled through on the customer view side of things.

Read more about it here:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools/

Firstly when you are editing your Placement.info file, it does not always pull through immediately, I find that you have to recycle the application pool in IIS for the specific site.

Also get a better understanding of placement info here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info

Secondly you need to understand the order in which elements are being loaded before you change any placement of it.

**I followed the following steps:**

- Created a blog called 'blog'
- Edited the Content Type called 'Blog' and added the a field called 'image' as a 'Media Library Picker Field'
- I viewed the '/blog' in the customer side and inspected it with 'shape tracer'
- I found that the detail view was loading for the blog description/summary;
- The 'Parts_Blogs_Blog_Description' which is the summary was loading in 'content:before' by default;
- The 'Fields_MediaLibraryPicker' was loading at 'content:after'

**So, in this case you will have to change both:**

If you had to place both in 'content:before', then Orchard would still not know which one to put first. This is what you need to put in your placement.info file:

```
<Match ContentType="Blog">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
      <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-image="Content:1"
             Parts_Blogs_Blog_Description="Content:2" />
    </Match>
</Match>
```

If you want to do this for Blog Posts, you will do it exactly the same. But just refer to the blog post content type. The 'Media Library Picker Field' was called 'Images'. And you have to change the 'Part_Common_Body' placement.

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-Images="Content:1"
           Parts_Common_Body="Content:2" />
</Match>
```

To remove the Title and metadata from the images selected:

```
<Match ContentType="Image">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
      <Place Parts_Title_Summary="-"
             Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Also make sure that you selected images for the blog and blog posts. The Placement.info file can be found in your theme folder.

This was done in Orchard 1.10.2. I do not know if this will differ in other versions.

Comment: Wow i couldn't ask for more detail explanation than this, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should use the build in MediaLibraryPickerField as described in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025145/3153169), but in your case for the Blog instead of the BlogPost:

1. Attach a Media Library Picker Field to your 'Blog' content type
2. Edit your theme's placement.info and include something like this:

   ```
   <Match ContentType="Blog">
       <Match DisplayType="Summary">
           <Place Part_Image_Summary="Content:before" />
       </Match>
   </Match>
   ```

Comment: still not working, I attach the media library picker field in blog content type and named it Media. and then I open my Theme's placement.info and added  <Place Part_Image_Summary="Content:before" /> in the blog summary but the result in just a text "Media" and still cant find any image on the summary, please help

Comment: You should also pick an image of course on your blog item

Comment: all the post already had the image taken from image picker. But still not showing the image in the blog list summary, is there any tutorial (Step by step) to achieve this?